# Issues with delegating subdomain to AD server

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, bind, delegation

I have a working authorative BIND 9.8.4-P2 server on freebsd on domain `domain.com` with IP `192.168.0.3` and name `ns.domain.com` that I did not set up on my own. It is a hidden server from which a subset is published to the providers server.

I have configured an AD `ad.domain.com` server with DNS under the subdomain `corp.domain.com` with IP `192.168.0.5`

What works:

```
nslookup ad.domain.com 192.168.0.3
nslookup ns.domain.com 192.168.0.3

nslookup ns.domain.com 192.168.0.5
nslookup corp.domain.com 192.168.0.5
nslookup ad.corp.domain.com 192.168.0.5
```

What does not work:

```
nslookup corp.domain.com 192.168.0.3 => nxdomain
nslookup ad.corp.domain.com 192.168.0.3 => nxdomain
```

I configured it according to [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/673473/zone-delegation), however that does not work.

Here is the excerpt from the zone file (note the SOA line with the providers DNS as the file is published also to our provider):

```
 $TTL    86400
 @       86400   IN      SOA  ns.provider.com. hostmaster.ns.provider.com. (
                    2015070205      ; Serial number
                    86400           ; Refresh     1 day
                    7200            ; Retry       2 hours
                    604800          ; Expire      7 days
                    259200 )        ; Minimum TTL 3 days

; PRIMARY
            NS      ns.domain.com.
; secondaries
            NS      ns.provider.com.

; hosts
ns        IN      A       192.168.0.3
ad        IN      A       192.168.0.5
```

I now added the line

```
corp.domain.com.  IN      NS      ad.domain.com.
```

at the end but the delegation does not work.

The dig output for `dig @ad.domain.com corp.domain.com ns` is

```
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 18273
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;corp.domain.com.       IN  NS

;; ANSWER SECTION:
corp.domain.com.    3600    IN  NS  ad.corp.domain.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ad.corp.domain.com. 1200    IN  A   192.168.0.5

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.0.5#53(192.168.0.5)
;; WHEN: Thu Jul  2 09:53:37 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 72
```

while for `dig @ns.domain.com corp.domain.com ns` it is

```
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 46841
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;corp.domain.com.       IN  NS

;; Query time: 35 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.0.3#53(192.168.0.3)
;; WHEN: Thu Jul  2 09:55:20 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 39
```

Looking at [this thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/584583/dns-referral-delegation-which-dns-is-responsible-how-to-delegate-the-right-w?lq=1), could the issue be that the entry is not in the providers nameserver? I mean, any server in our network asks `192.168.0.3` for dns and with host name updates, the changes are visible immediately on the local network, without pushing them to the provider's DNS.

And just for the record, I also tried [this approach](https://serverfault.com/questions/475094/how-to-do-delegation-on-bind-server?rq=1) with similar results.

Additionally, here is an excerpt from the AD's DNS (not translated)

```
_msdcs          
_sites          
_tcp            
_udp            
DomainDnsZones          
ForestDnsZones
(identisch mit übergeordnetem Ordner)   Autoritätsursprung (SOA)    [682], ad.corp.domain.com., hostmaster.corp.domain.com.
(identisch mit übergeordnetem Ordner)   Namenserver (NS)    ad.corp.domain.com.
(identisch mit übergeordnetem Ordner)   Host (A)    192.168.0.5
ad  Host (A)    192.168.0.5 Static
```

Answer (score 0):

You're specifying a delegation. If you want corp.domain.com to resolve to something, you need (below the delegation):

```
$ORIGIN corp.domain.com.
    IN  A   some.ip.add.ress
ad  IN  A   192.168.0.5
```

and verify that the delegation (NS) is correct in the authoritative server for corp.domain.com

**EDIT:**

is

```
@       86400   IN      SOA  ns.provider.com. hostmaster.ns.provider.com. (
```

supposed to be

```
 @       86400   IN      SOA  ns.domain.com. hostmaster.ns.domain.com. (
```

Also, are you trying to delegate `corp.domain.com` to *ad.domain.com* or *ad.corp.domain.com*?

Lastly, please include the config from the 192.168.0.5 server.

Comment: When I add that at the end, I see no difference. (I suspect you meant `ad` instead of `as`)

Comment: yes, post corrected

Comment: Yes, the SOA line is strange, but the file is published on our providers DNS and it works like that for host names. I don't know enough about  hidden servers to judge whether this does any harm. Actually, I don't know  where to delegate to, both `ad.domain.com` and `ad.corp.domain.com`point to the same, I need AD to work, so the second seems reasonable. I updated the question with more information.

Comment: Is this an AD domain,  or just DNS?

Comment: corp is an AD domain, domain.com ist just DNS. That way, I don't need to set the SRV entries or enable dynamic updates, I let that handle the Windows 2012R2 DNS Server

Comment: So your domain root is `.corp` or `corp.domain.com`? Because having "normal" DNS for domain.com and an AD domain on corp.domain.com sounds very convoluted to get them to play nicely. Also, it appears your zone has an SOA for `provider.com`, but I don't see config for `domain.com`. I'm still somewhat confused but what I think you're trying to do is delegate a `domain.com` address from a `provider.com` zone.